CPP constructor overload, variables not initialized if nested constructor is called "java-like"
I have an issue defining different constructors calling each other from the same class:
class
MyClass
{ 
    public: 
    int m_a;
    inline MyClass(void) { MyClass(42); }; //java-like
    inline MyClass( int a ): m_a(a){};
};


class 
MyClass1 
{
    public: 
    int m_a;
    inline MyClass1(void) : MyClass1(42){ };
    inline MyClass1( int a ): m_a(a){};
};


MyClass mc;
MyClass1 mc1;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
printf("MyClass %d\n", mc.m_a); // prints 0 (42 expected)
printf("MyClass1 %d\n", mc1.m_a); // prints 42
}

Why does the first nested constructor call fails (it returns 0 instead of the expected 42)?

MyClass(42); creates a temporary MyClass object and throws it away.

Re: "java-like" -- C++ isn't Java.

Note that you can also write MyClass(42); inside main, with the same effect. C++ and Java are very different languages.

@molbdnilo I just cannot grasp why java-like construction syntax is kept valid, what's the pro of allowing constructing an object without a reference to it so, de-facto, not being able to access it? I'm not even getting a warning from the compiler.

@DDS It has been this way since the dawn of time (i.e. at least since C was created). You don't get a warning because the constructor could have a side effect. If you use an expression that definitely doesn't have a side effect - like 2 - compilers may emit a warning. (And it's not "java-like"; C++ is much older than Java, and Java's syntax is similar to C++ in order to entice C++ programmers to switch. In most other aspects, Java is more similar to Pascal.)

You can mark the second constructor [[nodiscard]] to get a warning.

Side note : different languages really work very differently. Do not try to directly translate what you know from one language to another.

@DDS -- void f(const MyClass&); f(MyClass(42));. More generally, there's not much to be gained, and a great deal of complexity added, to require diagnosing inappropriate uses of temporary objects. If you don't want it, don't write it. C++ isn't java-like: it doesn't treat you like a child; it doesn't try to hold your hand

Unrelated note: putting inline keywords here is useless, as the methods are defined in the class itself. I highly suspect you didn't understand what inline really means: it is for the ODR (one definition rule), not for inlining.

@prapin It also affects inlining and GCC documentation even mentions it directly. It's not for forced inlining.

Delegating_constructor syntax is
MyClass() : MyClass(42) {}

You currently construct a temporary object with the "java-like" way.
